# Porque no me trae la grafica?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Buenas Tardes Estoy realizando una gráfica con js y ya tengo la gráfica a la hora de mostrarla no se visualiza
Este es script

```
$(function () {
var tope = 100;
var acum = 73;
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Ventas'
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: -160,
        endAngle: 160,
        background: [{
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#FFF'],
                    [1, '#333']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '109%'
        }, {
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#333'],
                    [1, '#FFF']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 1,
            outerRadius: '107%'
        }, {
            // default background
        }, {
            backgroundColor: '#DDD',
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '105%',
            innerRadius: '103%'
        }]
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: tope*1.2,

        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        minorTickWidth: 1,
        minorTickLength: 10,
        minorTickPosition: 'inside',
        minorTickColor: '#666',

        tickPixelInterval: 30,
        tickWidth: 2,
        tickPosition: 'inside',
        tickLength: 10,
        tickColor: '#666',
        labels: {
            step: 2,
            rotation: 'auto'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'x $10 Mill'
        },
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: tope*.2,
            color: '#DF5353' // rojo
        },{
            from: tope*.2,
            to: tope*.4,
            color: '#FE9A2E' // rojo
        }, {
            from: tope*.4,
            to: tope*.75,
            color: '#DDDF0D' // naranja
        }, {
            from: tope*.75,
            to: tope,
            color: '#55BF3B' // Amarillo
        }, {
            from: tope,
            to: tope*1.2,
            color: '#58D3F7' // Verde
        }]
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Acum',
        data: [acum],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        }
    }]

},
// Add some life
function (chart) {
    if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
        setInterval(function () {
            var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
                newVal,
                inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

            //newVal = point.y + inc;
            newVal = acum;
            if (newVal < 0 || newVal > tope*1.2) {
                newVal = point.y - inc;
            }

            point.update(newVal);

        }, 3000);
    }
});
});
```

¿Cual puede ser el Error, Porque no me funciona?
Agradecería mucho algo de ayuda.

Comment: Cuales librerias esta usando?

Comment: Byron, el OP está usando [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). @CristianDagnover, decir "no funciona" **no ayuda** en nada. Debes agregar más datos, por ejemplo si ya viste la consola del navegador en busca de errores, etc. Cuando preguntes trata de seguir [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) esquema.

Comment: correcto pero  highcharts, al igual que muchas librería, no consta solo de un js. como podes verificar en es cdn, esta librería tiene bastantes archivos. http://code.highcharts.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo único que te falta es incluir el archivo `highcharts-more.js`, o quizás tengas referenciada una versión antigua, pero así funciona bien para mi:

```js
$(function () {
var tope = 100;
var acum = 73;
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Ventas'
    },
    pane: {
        startAngle: -160,
        endAngle: 160,
        background: [{
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#FFF'],
                    [1, '#333']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '109%'
        }, {
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#333'],
                    [1, '#FFF']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 1,
            outerRadius: '107%'
        }, {
            // default background
        }, {
            backgroundColor: '#DDD',
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '105%',
            innerRadius: '103%'
        }]
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: tope*1.2,

        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        minorTickWidth: 1,
        minorTickLength: 10,
        minorTickPosition: 'inside',
        minorTickColor: '#666',

        tickPixelInterval: 30,
        tickWidth: 2,
        tickPosition: 'inside',
        tickLength: 10,
        tickColor: '#666',
        labels: {
            step: 2,
            rotation: 'auto'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'x $10 Mill'
        },
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: tope*.2,
            color: '#DF5353' // rojo
        },{
            from: tope*.2,
            to: tope*.4,
            color: '#FE9A2E' // rojo
        }, {
            from: tope*.4,
            to: tope*.75,
            color: '#DDDF0D' // naranja
        }, {
            from: tope*.75,
            to: tope,
            color: '#55BF3B' // Amarillo
        }, {
            from: tope,
            to: tope*1.2,
            color: '#58D3F7' // Verde
        }]
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Acum',
        data: [acum],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        }
    }]

},
// Add some life
function (chart) {
    if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
        setInterval(function () {
            var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
                newVal,
                inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

            //newVal = point.y + inc;
            newVal = acum;
            if (newVal < 0 || newVal > tope*1.2) {
                newVal = point.y - inc;
            }

            point.update(newVal);

        }, 3000);
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Como recomendación, debes siempre verificar por ti mismo la consola de errores, ya que claramente reportaba el error 17.

Comment: Si no estás seguro de la causa del problema ni de su solución y tengas sospechas como ésta, por favor, escríbelas como comentario. Puedes copiar tu respuesta y pegarla como comentario y luego eliminar ésta respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por su comentario, pero con los insumos suministrados, logre reproducir error, en la consola indicaba código 17, este debería ser un lugar de aprendizaje, cordial, pero es común que en SO no se acoja bien a los nuevos usuarios

Comment: Byron, los _nuevos usuarios_ son bienvenidos. El sitio tiene su propia cultura y el espacio _Tu Respuesta_ está destinado para aquellos aportes que plantean una solución al problema original. Leyendo tu aporte, veo que plantea una solución, pero está redactado de manera que pareciera que pide una aclaración al usuario, y no como una respuesta que plantea una solución. Mi sugerencia es que sea editado para reflejar la solución.

Comment: Es más, voy a editarlo yo, y si no estás de acuerdo con la edición, puedes revertirla.

Comment: Gracias @jachguate, definitivamente queda mucho mas claro.

Comment: +1 por la respuesta ;)

Comment: Buenas Tardes, los js ya los tengo agregados dentro del código